# Extracting data from erlang using fxml

Tags: erlang, fxml, ejabberd

I am using ejabberd version : 16.04
I receive a packet like this :

But i am getting only : `g\u000ag`
I want to get the contents as it is like so  : `g\\u000ag`
No escape of additonal \

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you show us how you check the content of `Body`? Because I bet you got what you have stored in the body of `Pkt`.

```
1> Body = <<"g\\u000ag">>.
<<"g\\u000ag">>
2> io:put_chars(Body), io:nl().
g\u000ag
ok
3> io:format("Body send_to_offline_resources_sms_push ~s~n",[Body]).
Body send_to_offline_resources_sms_push g\u000ag
ok
4> io:format("Body send_to_offline_resources_sms_push ~p~n",[Body]).
Body send_to_offline_resources_sms_push <<"g\\u000ag">>
ok
```

Comment: ?INFO_MSG("Body send_to_offline_resources_sms_push ~s",[Body])

Comment: @pawansaxena `~s` means output string which is technically same as `io:put_chars/1`. So it works as I expected. There is not a problem.

Comment: But as you can see that body is  : "g\\u000ag"

but i am getting only one backslash : g\u000ag

how can i get both as : g\\u000ag

Comment: @pawansaxena: No, in your body is only one backslash. What you see is what you need to write to shell or source code to get one backslash. Hence two backslashes.

Comment: Thanks i got that.One more thing i want to ask  is to replace occurences of \n

but on erlang shell i get \n interpreted like : a\nb as :
a
b

and not a\nb
how can i replace this \n.